# ¿Como soluciono números basura en la terminal?. Lenguaje C

Tags: c, terminal

verán, tengo un código que consta de solo variables, printf y scanf. pero al ejecutarlo, en la terminal aparecen números basura (aleatorios) que no sé de donde salieron. Trabajo en Dev++ y hasta en compiladores online me sucede igual.
Este es el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Spanish");
    int cal1, cal2, cal3, cal4, cal5, cal6, cal7, sum=cal1+cal2+cal3+cal4+cal5+cal6+cal7;
    
    printf("Digite la calificación: %i"); scanf("%i", &cal1);
    
    printf("Digite la calificación: %i"); scanf("%i", &cal2);
    
    printf("Digite la calificación: %i"); scanf("%i", &cal3);
    
    printf("Digite la calificación: %i"); scanf("%i", &cal4);
    
    printf("Digite la calificación: %i"); scanf("%i", &cal5);
    
    printf("Digite la calificación: %i"); scanf("%i", &cal6);
    
    printf("Digite la calificación: %i"); scanf("%i", &cal7);
    
    int prom=sum/3;
    
    printf("Su calificación es de: %i", prom);
    
    return 0;
}
```

y el primer output es este:

```
Digite la calificación: -1195515661.
```

igual con lo que sigue. ¿Alguien sabe que está mal?

Comment: Mi C está oxidado pero, ¿estás imprimiendo la dirección en memoria del dato cal1, etc?

Comment: Con el `%i` en `printf("Digite la calificación: %i");` le estas diciendo que le vas a pasar un entero, y luego no se lo pasas. Que esperabas que hiciera el programa?

Answer (score 0):

te comento, tu estas colocando en el:

```
 printf("Digite su calificación:%i");
```

en el momento que colocas el `%i` estas diciéndole a printf que mostraras luego de la cadena un valor entero pero no lo haces toma de ejemplo tu ultima linea:

```
printf("Su calificación es de: %i", prom);
```

acá le dices que mostraras un entero y ese entero es la variable prom

te muestro mi solucion :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;

int main()

{

    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Spanish");
    int cal1, cal2, cal3, cal4, cal5, cal6, cal7, sum;

    printf("Digite la calificación: "); scanf("%i", &cal1);

    printf("Digite la calificación: "); scanf("%i", &cal2);

    printf("Digite la calificación: "); scanf("%i", &cal3);

    printf("Digite la calificación: "); scanf("%i", &cal4);

    printf("Digite la calificación: "); scanf("%i", &cal5);

    printf("Digite la calificación: "); scanf("%i", &cal6);

    printf("Digite la calificación: "); scanf("%i", &cal7);
    sum=cal1+cal2+cal3+cal4+cal5+cal6+cal7;
    int prom=sum/7;

    printf("Su promedio es de: %i", prom);

    return 0;
}
```

coloque la suma debajo de todo ya cuando los valores de  cal1....cal7 tengan ya asignados los que el usuario escribió y no se muestre un numero "aleatorio"